# Creating a program that counts down from a number and plays music at 0 using javafx

Tags: java, audio, javafx, counter

Trying to create a program that displays a pane where a user inputs a number and press the Enter key.

The program should then count down from that number every one second.

Once the counter reaches 0, it should play a sound.

I am having trouble getting my program to work, and not entirely sure where I have messed up or what I am doing wrong.

So in theory, if the user put in "30" it should start counting down to 0, subtracting by one each time. 29 ... 28 ... 27 ... etc

Here's my code:

```
public class Counter extends Application {

    private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/common/sample.mp4";
    private TextField text = new TextField();
    int countDown = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);


        // create a pane and add a TextField
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(text);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));

        // create a new animation
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {
                if (countDown > 0) {
                    countDown--;
                    text.setText(Integer.toString(countDown));
                }
                else {
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                }
              }));
              animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        // create and register a handler
        text.setOnAction(e -> text.setText(text.getText()));
        text.setOnAction(e -> animation.play());

        // create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

EDIT: upon running, I get this long list of errors:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Counter
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Counter.<init>(Counter.java:18)
    ... 13 more
Exception running application Counter
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: *am having trouble getting my program to work*.... what exactly is going on with the application

Comment: Sorry, had a ton of errors. Edited it into the post, but someone already helped me out.

Thanks for inquiring guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

- You're reading the text field and setting `countDown` immediately, i.e. before the user has input anything. You need to read the text when the user executes the action on the text field.
- You're setting the cycle count of the animation to `INDEFINITE` instead of to the value of `countDown`
- You set the cycle count once, instead of setting it when the user commits the text field
- You're setting the `onAction` property of the button twice. `onAction` is just a property like any other: if you set it and then set it again, it will hold only the second value, i.e. the first call to `textField.setOnAction(...)` won't have any effect.
- The first action handler on the text field doesn't do anything anyway: it sets the text of the text field to the current text of the text field.

You need something like this:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Counter extends Application {

    private static final String MEDIA_URL = "http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/common/sample.mp4";
    private TextField text = new TextField();
    int countDown;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

        // create a pane and add a TextField
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(text);
        text.setFont(Font.font("Times", 35));

        // create a new animation
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {
            if (countDown > 0) {
                countDown--;
                text.setText(Integer.toString(countDown));
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        }));

        // create and register a handler
        // text.setOnAction(e -> text.setText(text.getText()));
        text.setOnAction(e -> {
            countDown = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
            animation.setCycleCount(countDown + 1);
            animation.play();
        });

        // create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Application.launch(args);

    }

}
```

There are a bunch of other things you should probably address (e.g. what happens if the user commits an action on the text field while the animation is in progress, etc) but this will at least get it to "work".

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly!

Yeah, been at it all day making different programs. Really couldn't figure this one out --- thanks a ton!

Comment: As I pointed out at the bottom of the answer, it doesn't actually work perfectly - there are still multiple issues you should fix. However, I am not going to do all your homework for you.

Comment: "... it doesn't actually work perfectly."

I was saying it works perfectly in that it now does what I intended for it to do.

"... I am not going to do all your homework for you."

No need to be rude. I do appreciate your help and the pointers that you added, regardless.

Comment: I wasn't meaning to be rude. Responses of the form "Hey, this works" always make me think the poster is simply going to copy the code and not make much effort to think about how/why it works. (If that's not the case, then great, but it does come across that way, especially when there was fairly minimal effort to diagnose the problem in the first place.) I was wanting to make sure you were aware that there was quite a lot more to do here.